# having trouble testing point/geometry intersections in sf

Tags: r, gis, r-sf

i am trying to figure out how to use `sf_intersects()` to test whether or not point data that i have falls inside the geometries of some map data i have.

data i'm working with: https://osfm.fire.ca.gov/media/5818/fhszs19sn.zip

other data i'm working with too: https://osfm.fire.ca.gov/media/7564/c19fhszl06_5.zip

for now, i'm just trying to see if this data falls in the polygons of the above shapefile:

```
la_test_points <- data.frame(y = runif(1000, 33.6, 34.8), x = runif(1000, -119, -117.6))
```

when i put my map data and point data together, this is what it looks like:

[image]

so far, so good. now i attempt to test point/geometry intersections. as the figure suggests, i should be able to get quite a few.

```
# changing coordinate system of map created by shape file

la_fire_sra <- st_transform(st_as_sf(la_fire_sra), crs = 3857)

# merging test points with map data

la_test_points_merged <- st_as_sf(la_test_points, coords = c('y', 'x'), crs = st_crs(la_fire_sra))

# seeing if points fall within any of the geometries in the shapefile

la_test_points_merged <- la_test_points_merged %>%
  mutate(intersection = st_intersects(geometry, la_fire_sra))
```

that last bit is where it all goes wrong. rstudio doesn't throw an error, but when i print `la_test_points_merged` to see my results, this is what i see:

```
> la_test_points_merged
Simple feature collection with 1000 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 33.60155 ymin: -118.9959 xmax: 34.79907 ymax: -117.6015
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
First 10 features:
Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

the last line above is in red.

when i try using `st_intersection()` instead of `st_intersects()`, i get a different error:

```
> la_test_points_merged <- la_test_points_merged %>%
+   mutate(intersection = st_intersection(geometry, la_fire_sra))
Error in `stopifnot()`:
! Problem while computing `intersection = st_intersection(geometry, la_fire_sra)`.
x `intersection` must be size 1000 or 1, not 0.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

i would like to end up with a result like [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282750/identify-polygon-containing-point-with-r-sf-package/343477#343477) that tells me whether or not each of the points in `la_test_points` is contained by any of the geometry values in `la_fire_sa`.

how can i fix this to make my code work? i have looked at lots of other similar questions, but i can't seem to find any answers that apply to my current situation.

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What would you like to end up with?

Comment: @mrhellmann i would like to end up with a dataframe that tells me whether or not each of the points in `la_test_points` is contained by any of the `geometry` values in `la_fire_sa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the points to the shapefile, and the result will show you the fire hazard for each point that falls within a polygon. The default for an `st_join` is `st_intersects`, but you can change it if you'd like.

Below I've used one of the shapefiles you linked. If you need to use both you can combine them for a single dataframe with all the polygons. Looks like they have different columns though, so some cleaning might be needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

set.seed(3) #to make la_test_points reproducible
a <- read_sf('fhszs06_3_19.shp')

#  Create synthetic data, make it an sf object, and set the crs
la_test_points <- data.frame(y = runif(1000, 33.6, 34.8), x = runif(1000, -119, -117.6)) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c('x','y')) %>%
  st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(a))

# join the points with the fire hazard area
joined <- st_join(la_test_points, a)

# the sf dataframe, lots of NA's so they're removed for a look:
joined %>% filter(!is.na(HAZ_CODE)) %>% head()
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 5 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 125951 ymin: -433789.6 xmax: 177186.8 ymax: -369094
#> Projected CRS: NAD_1983_Albers
#>   SRA HAZ_CODE HAZ_CLASS Shape_Leng Shape_Area                   geometry
#> 1 SRA        3 Very High   613618.0  686671532 POINT (163249.3 -395328.4)
#> 2 SRA        3 Very High   250826.8  233414399 POINT (127980.6 -433789.6)
#> 3 SRA        3 Very High   613618.0  686671532 POINT (167675.9 -386506.6)
#> 4 SRA        3 Very High   391522.6  297194108   POINT (143421.2 -369094)
#> 5 SRA        2      High   208122.8  211364977 POINT (177186.8 -388738.9)
#> 6 SRA        3 Very High   613618.0  686671532   POINT (125951 -399105.6)

# Plotting points, colored according to fire hazard code
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = a) +
  geom_sf(data = joined, aes(color = HAZ_CODE)) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = 'yellow', high = 'red')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Edit to address joining the example shapefiles:

```
# Keeping the columns that the example shapefiles have in common,
#  and joining them together.
ax <- a %>% select(HAZ_CODE, HAZ_CLASS, Shape_Leng, Shape_Area)
bx <- b %>% select(HAZ_CODE, HAZ_CLASS, Shape_Leng, Shape_Area)

fires <- rbind(ax, bx)
head(fires)

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 4 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 151597.9 ymin: -470591.9 xmax: 198216 ymax: -443900.4
Projected CRS: NAD83 / California Albers
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  HAZ_CODE HAZ_CLASS Shape_Leng Shape_Area                                                                   geometry
     <int> <chr>          <dbl>      <dbl>                                                         <MULTIPOLYGON [m]>
1        3 Very High      5415.   1355567. (((152996.8 -469302.2, 152996.9 -469302.2, 152965.9 -469339.9, 152957.5 -…
2        3 Very High      2802.    423658. (((153701.7 -468506, 153703.9 -468590.6, 153708 -468758.1, 153707.6 -4687…
3        3 Very High       802.     32272. (((191491 -449977.1, 191494.3 -449973.2, 191517.3 -449946.5, 191521.5 -44…
4        3 Very High      1097.     40800. (((182453.8 -445649.1, 182216.3 -445706.6, 182215.4 -445655.7, 182170.4 -…
5        3 Very High     59226.   9379764. (((198201 -446611.2, 198199.9 -446580, 198199.1 -446551.3, 198200 -446580…
6        3 Very High      1255.     70800. (((186617.7 -444161.6, 186619 -444164.5, 186630.5 -444192.8, 186561.8 -44…
```

Comment: thank you very much. this has been extremely helpful. one more question though: how should i join the two files? i've tried this as well but my results weren't correct.

Comment: @qwerty See the edit to the answer posted above. Joining(`rbind`-ing) the example shapefiles by keeping the columns in common.

Comment: pardon my late reply, but thank you very much! you've been a huge help.